# Is there any advantage to having an app manifest file to desktop users?

Tags: desktop, progressive-web-apps

According to https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/ having an app manifest file gives mobile users a better experience with my site by allowing them to add it to their home screen and giving it some special launching properties from there. Do any of these benefits apply to desktop users, especially those who do not chose to add a shortcut to my site to their desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main use of manifest files is to allow site developers better control over how their sites behave when added to and launched from non-browser environments. If users don't install the app outside of the browser, a manifest doesn't do much on desktop or mobile.

The case for implementing a manifest file is not about desktop vs mobile. It's about if you expect/want users to use the app outside the browser.